# Problematic C macro

Tags: c, macros

I've recently begun to write C macros and the following code does somehow not 
output the expected text to screen. The problem lies with defining print_int where I want to use print_int macro as taking integer parameter with a desired text and print out the integer value with any text that is written inside the function (not in #define section). The code does not print out "Total is" text to screen. How can I correct the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define     print_int(integ, a)     printf("%d", a)
#define     read(j)                 scanf("%d", &j)
#define     print_free(s)           printf(s)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    _add_();
}

_add_()
{
    int c, j, total;

    print_free("Enter first number: ");
    read(c);

    print_free("Enter second number: ");
    read(j);

    total = c + j;
    print_int("Total is %d", total);
}
```

Comment: Rule #1 of macros: name them in ALL_CAPS! Rule #2: parenthesize the arguments in the macro expansion.

Comment: Great hint! Will keep that in mind next time I define :)

Comment: Rule #3: if macros don't simplify the use of the function they call, there's no point in using them, in fact, they make your code less readable and harder to debug. Just use `printf()` directly. It's simple, it's easy, everybody understands it, and you'll get useful error messages. Macros just obscure all of that for no reason.

Comment: Rather than your `print_free()` macro, I suggest `#define print_string(s) printf("%s", (s))`. Passing a string directly as the format string causes problems if the string happens to contain `%` characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change macro definition of `print_int` from

```
#define     print_int(integ, a)     printf("%d", a)
```

to

```
#define     print_int(integ, a)     printf(integ, a)
```

BTW, function `_add` should have a return type and a declaration prior to its first call, otherwise it will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Awesome! Seems like it will work except I got 1 more error which opens up Makefile.win source code and point at 
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
$(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
and the error is: "Multiple definition of _add_" Id returned 1 exit status.

Comment: @CalFox; Read the last line of the answer.

Comment: instead of `#define     print_int(integ, a)     printf(integ, a)  ` you can also use `#define     print_int     printf`

Comment: @mch Without paranteses, well it might work but why ignore paranteses?

Comment: because the arguments are equal, so `print_int` will be replaced by `printf`. It's not necessary to add the arguments into the macro.

Comment: @mch The same is not true for scanf as far as I see.. Just tested and the end result was a gibberish number printed out to screen and didn't even asked me to enter anything.

Comment: @CalFox I never wrote anything about the `read` macro. I wrote about the `print_int` macro.

Comment: @mch yeah well I thought you meant in general form when pinpointing print_int macro which made me think that rule applied to all macros but thanks. That hint just added +2 point to my knowledge :)

Comment: I'm not sure why the `print_int` macro needs two parameters. If it's just supposed to print an integer value in decimal, why not `#define print_int(a) printf("%d", (a))`? With two parameters, you might as well just call `printf` directly (in fact you might as well do that anyway).

Comment: @KeithThompson; Yes. You are right. I just pointed out what should be changed to the OP's snippet to work it well.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just include the "Total is" to your macro definition, then remove `integ` so you only need to pass 1 element.

`#define     print_int(a)     printf("Total is %d", a)`

`print_int(total);`

Sidenote, I'd recommend you edit your `_add_` function.

- the `_varName_` format is used by standard library functions. Avoid misinterpretations.
- declare data type (ie. void, int)
- good coding practice is to generally declare the function (without the function definition yet) before `main()`, then supply the definition after `main()`. something like this:

  ```
  void vAdd();         //declaration
  int main(){
      /*code*/
  }
  void vAdd()          //definition
  {
      /*code*/
  }
  ```